# Problem getting data from database in Android Kotlin Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I'm new to mobile developpment. I am trying to get LiveData from the Room database in a Fragment, I get no errors but the Observer callback is null. My database contains data, i can access the login. All help is welcome :)

StepCount

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "stepcount", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Users::class, parentColumns = ["userId"], childColumns = ["userId"], onDelete = CASCADE)])
data class StepCount (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    val userId: Int,

    val date: String,

    val hour: Int,

    var steps: Int = 0
)
```

StepCountDao

```kotlin
@Dao
interface StepCountDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM stepcount")
    fun getAllStepTable(): LiveData<List<StepCount>>
}
```

StepCountRepository

```kotlin
class StepCountRepository(private val dao: StepCountDao) {
    fun getAllStepsTable() : LiveData<List<StepCount>> {
        return dao.getAllStepTable()
    }
}
```

StepCountViewModelFactory

```kotlin
class StepCountViewModelFactory(
    private val repository: StepCountRepository,
            private val application: Application): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(StepCountViewModel::class.java)) {
            return StepCountViewModel(repository, application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown View Model Class")
    }
}
```

StepCountViewModel

```kotlin
class StepCountViewModel(private val repository: StepCountRepository, application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), Observable {
    private var _allStepsTable = MutableLiveData<List<StepCount>>()
    val allStepsTable : LiveData<List<StepCount>>
        get() = _allStepsTable

    fun getAllStepsTable() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
          _allStepsTable.postValue(repository.getAllStepsTable().value)
        }
    }
}
```

DayFragment

```kotlin
class DayFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var stepCountViewModel: StepCountViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dao = UsersDatabase.getInstance(application).stepCountDao()
        val repository = StepCountRepository(dao)
        val factory = StepCountViewModelFactory(repository, application)

        stepCountViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(StepCountViewModel::class.java)

        val prefs = application.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val userId = prefs.getInt("userId", -1)
        Log.d("userId", userId.toString())

        stepCountViewModel.allStepsTable.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { allStepsTable ->
            if (allStepsTable !== null)
                Log.i("DAYFRAG_obs_all_steps", allStepsTable.toString())
        })
        stepCountViewModel.getAllStepsTable()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly different answer than the question asked as
LiveData is not recommended in dataflow ([source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#livedata-in-architecture)).

If you check [the Advanced Kotlin Coroutines code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines#0), I think it will help you develop the function.

Here’s an example:

**`StepCountDao`**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface StepCountDao{
   @Query("SELECT * FROM stepcount")
   fun getAllStepTable(): Flow<List<StepCount>>
}
```

**`StepCountRepository`**

```kotlin
class StepCountRepository(private val dao: StepCountDao){
 private var _eventProductList = MutableSharedFlow<List<StepCount>>()
    val eventProductList = _eventProductList.asSharedFlow()

    private suspend fun eventAllStepTable(allStepTable: List<StepCount>){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            _eventProductList.emit(allStepTable)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getAllStepsTable() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            eventAllStepTable(dao.getAllStepTable().shareIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO), SharingStarted.Lazily).first())
        }
    }
}
```

**`StepCountViewModel`**

```
class StepCountViewModel(...){
    val event : SharedFlow<List<StepCount>>
        get() = repository.eventProductList

    fun getStepTable(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getAllStepsTable()
        }
    }
   }
}
```

**`DayFragment`**

```
class DayFragment: Fragment(){
   ... 
   override onCreateView(...){
     repeatOnStarted {
            viewModel.event.collect{
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate: $it")
            }
        }
     viewModel.getStepTable()
   }
}
```

**Extensions**

```kotlin
fun LifecycleOwner.repeatOnStarted(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LiveData has to be used reactively. This code:

```
fun getAllStepsTable() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      _allStepsTable.postValue(repository.getAllStepsTable().value)
    }
}
```

takes the initial `null` value of the LiveData and passes it to the other LiveData, one time only, so it will always be null.

It's actually useless that you launch a coroutine here because you aren't doing anything that needs to be done off the main thread. Getting a LiveData value and posting a value are both non-blocking actions.

But it's also pointless that you do this at all. You can just pass through the original LiveData since you aren't modifying its value. Your ViewModel can be changed to:

```
class StepCountViewModel(private val repository: StepCountRepository, application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), Observable {
    val allStepsTable: LiveData<List<StepCount>> = repository.getAllStepsTable()
}
```

In general, the only time you should ever be reading `LiveData.value` is when you are using the old value to help compute the next value right before posting it.